# Script from HTML to VUE - change bg color on click

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, syntax

Currently I'm able to change color of a div, that from now on I will refer to as 'Cell', in a vanilla html file as follows:

```
<script type=text/javascript>

    var type = -1;

    function colorCell() {
        if(type==0){
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = ' #fdcb6e ';
        }else if(type==1){
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = ' #fab1a0 ';
        }else if(type==2){
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = ' #fd79a8 ';
        }else if(type==-1){
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = ' azure ';
        }
    }

    function delay(){
        type=0;
    }
    function panne(){
        type=1;
    }
    function reserved(){
        type=2;
    }
    function clean(){
        type=-1;
    }
</script>
```

Cell can change to different colors according to the type parameter. Type changes when other buttons (not cells) are clicked.

Any orientation of how to get this done in VUE? I can't get it working.

EDIT:

To add information to proposed problem, I need each cell to be colored only when clicked. Cells are formed in a iterative way as follows:

```
    <div class="body">
        <div v-for="column in 25" :key="column.id" class="column">
          <div v-for="row in 10" :key="row.id" class="frame">
                <span v-if="column == 1">ROW-NAME</span>
                <div v-else class="selector"><b-button @click="colorCell($event)"  /></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with a component that looks something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div :style="{ backgroundColor }">Cell</div>
    <button @click="delay">delay</button>
    <button @click="panne">panne</button>
    <button @click="reserved">reserved</button>
    <button @click="clean">clean</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      type: -1,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    backgroundColor() {
      if (this.type == 0) {
        return '#fdcb6e';
      } else if (this.type == 1) {
        return '#fab1a0';
      } else if (this.type == 2) {
        return '#fd79a8';
      } else if (this.type == -1) {
        return 'azure';
      }
      return '';
    }
  },
  methods: {
    delay() {
      this.type = 0;
    },
    panne() {
      this.type = 1;
    },
    reserved() {
      this.type = 2;
    },
    clean() {
      this.type = -1;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

In order to colour the cells individually you could do it like this (note: you were trying to use `column.id` and `row.id` but these properties do not exist - `column` and `row` are integers):

```
    <div class="body">
        <div v-for="column in 25" :key="column" class="column">
          <div v-for="row in 10" :key="row" class="frame" :ref="`${column}-${row}`">
                <span v-if="column == 1">ROW-NAME</span>
                <div v-else class="selector"><b-button @click="colorCell(column, row)"  /></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
colorCell(col, row) {
  const el = this.$refs[`${col}-${row}`][0];
  // Update the colour of the individual cell here e.g. el.style.backgroundcolor = '#fdcb6e'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is close to what I need but proposed script colors all my cells when one of the 4 buttons is clicked and I forgot to mention that I need each cell to be colored when clicked only. Check question update if you'd like to see my HTML code.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of how to update the cell colours individually.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I can't get this.$refs[`${col}-${row}`][0] to work, it says that page cannot read property '0' of undefined, and sincerely I'm kind of lost at this point. Can you give me any advice about that?

Comment: Did you add the `ref` property to the loop inside your template?

Comment: yes, as follows: <div v-for="row in 10" :key="row" class="frame" :ref="`${column}-${row}`">

Comment: Could you update your post with how your code looks currently - I'm not sure why this is throwing an error for you.

Comment: I was about to but I got it working, I was misplacing the method within 'computed' instead of methods. Also, it does work with row.id and column.id too. Thank you for all your help and I'm tagging your answer as the solver one.